# shifted keyboard input without pressing shift?

Tags: key-bindings

Is there a function that maps a keyboard input character to the character that would have been input if the shift key modifier was being pressed? For instance if I pass the input ?c it would return ?C, or if I pass the input ?2 it would return ?@.

Comment: Spontaneously, I don't think so since Emacs has no direct knowledge about keymaps. Hence, it can't know if shift 2 would be `@` (as used in the US) or `"` (which is used on some european layouts).

Comment: [Sticky Keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_keys) might be helpful for you. It's a feature of your operating system and/or keyboard, not Emacs.

Comment: If the goal is, for example, to bind a command to “Ctrl+Shift+2” in a way that's independent of the keyboard layout, I don't think Emacs provides a way to do this. Emacs's key binding philosophy is to be independent of the keyboard layout, for example up/down/left/right are P[revious]/N[ext]/B[ackward]/F[orward] and not WASD or ijkl. I don't think there's any code in Emacs to query the “base key” information when parsing an event from the operating system.

Answer (score -1):

You can probably do it with the function `event-apply-shift-modifier`. But it will depend on exactly what you're using it for (of course).

Comment: `event-apply-shift-modifier` reads an event, it doesn't take an event or a character as argument. You'd need to call `event-apply-modifier` directly. But that wouldn't do what the asker wants: it uppercases ASCII letters, but you can easily do that manually anyway. Other characters (non-ASCII letters, non-letters) are mapped to events with the shift bit set, not to a different base character.